# How can I make a DISPLAYED DATA(int) in a PARTICULAR COLUMN to be a hyperlink in a GRIDVIEW?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

How can I make a DISPLAYED DATA(int) of a PARTICULAR COLUMN to be a hyperlink in a GRIDVIEW, so when I click on that DATA it will display details of that chosen row line items.

Comment: My bet is you actually want to expand the current row and show details inline within an expandable/collapsible div. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video does something similiar to that. The details are not inline, but the concept is kind of what you're looking for. There is a grid view, and when clicking on an item, the details view below is populated with the row details. This may give you some ideas. Hope this helps.

http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-363.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you will give your details at another page, here is a [hyperlink column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.aspx) that points to a details page :

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn
    HeaderText="Show Details"
    DataNavigateUrlField="YourIntegerColumn"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="detailspage.aspx?id={0}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't think it is what you want, you might want to display details inside of hover text. This should work for you.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="LabelId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Details") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```